# Mapbox: create new GeoJsonSource with 20000 features takes a long time

Tags: android, ios, mapbox

When I try to show around 20000 items on the mapbox map in an android project, creating the GeoJsonSource takes a long time and it freezes the device for 8 to 10 seconds. Setting clustering on or off both takes this long. We have a similar problem in the iOS project.

For this project, we need clustering, so I as far as I know we need to use source to show the items for now.

Is there a way to make this faster or should I use an alternative method for showing clustered items?

My sourcecode:

```
new AsyncTask<Object, Object, FeatureCollection>() {

@Override
protected FeatureCollection doInBackground(Object... params) {

    List<Feature> featureArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    // currentMapPoiList contains 20000 location items:
    for (Poi p : currentMapPoiList) {
        JsonObject properties = new JsonObject();
        properties.addProperty("poitype", p.type);
        properties.addProperty("poiId", p.id);
        featureArrayList.add(Feature.fromGeometry(Point.fromCoordinates(Position.fromCoordinates(p.lon, p.lat)), properties, Integer.toString(p.id)));
    }

    FeatureCollection featureCollection = FeatureCollection.fromFeatures(featureArrayList);

    return featureCollection;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(FeatureCollection featureCollection) {
    super.onPostExecute(featureCollection);

    // Start timeconsuming code:
    poiSource = new GeoJsonSource(
            "sourcePoiItems",
            featureCollection,
            new GeoJsonOptions()
                .withCluster(true)
                .withClusterMaxZoom(8)
                .withClusterRadius(50));
    // End timeconsuming code

    mapboxMap.addSource(poiSource);
 ...
```

Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 0):

1. Move all time-consuming code out of the main thread. In your case `onPostExecute` is the main thread, so move timeconsuming section to `doInBackground`
2. Rethink your clustering logic. Do you really need these 20000 points to be clustered during the runtime? Maybe it can be pre-calculated somehow? Is it possible to load points depending on the current zoom level? Can you mark basic clusters using less points and then load more?

I'm not a mapbox expert, but I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. 1. The creation of the GeoJsonSource has to be done in main thread. 2. The calculation is done while creating the GeoJsonSource, so all this work is done by the mapbox framework. A solution for us might be to only load clustered items for one country only or to drop clustering all together for now.